# Express.js; use route variables on a global scale

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, spotify

I'm trying to use the Spotify API with my express.js server and need to access an Authorization code from a URL param. I have pulled this value using `let code = req.query.code` in the callback route I have specified in spotify dashboard. I then need to pass this into a POST request (I'm using the request module, as the docs for the api use cURL examples). However, I can not use the `code` variable globally, and want to avoid using global variables. How do I accomplish this?

Just to reiterate, I would like to use the code variable form this route:

```
app.get("/auth/spotify/callback", (req, res) => {
    let code = req.query.code;
    res.send({
      "code": code
    })
})
```

In this options JSON:

```
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic MmV...WU=',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/auth/spotify/callback'
    }
};
```

To then be used in this request call:

```
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
```

Whenever I run the server, it crashes and points to the instance of code used in the options JSON, claiming it isn't defined. This may be a simple JavaScript question, but I'm still learning back-end implementations.

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\Finn\Documents\Web\Projects\spotify application\server.js:30
      'code': code,
              ^

ReferenceError: code is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Finn\Documents\Web\Projects\spotify application\server.js:30:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

server.js:

```js
// ===server.js===
// MODULES
const request = require("request")
const express = require("express");
const app = new express();

// Auth vars
const [clientID, clientSecret, callbackURL] = ["2e...35", "5b...ae", "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Fspotify%2Fcallback"]

// redirects to spotify to get code
app.get("/auth/spotify", (req, res) => {
    // takes to auth and then redirects to localhost:5000/auth/spotify/callback
    res.redirect(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${callbackURL}&scope=user-top-read`)
})

// saves code in variable
app.get("/auth/spotify/callback", (req, res) => {
    let code = req.query.code;
    res.send({ "code": code })
})

var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic Basic MmV...WU=',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/auth/spotify/callback'
    }
};

// performs post request to receive access_token and refresh_token
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
});

// sets port variable
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// start server function
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is `options` in terms of scope?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should have specified. Options is at the global scope, outside any functions. I'll post the entire server.js later when I get a chance.

Comment: @code added error and full server.js file

Comment: Are you trying to send `request` AFTER the user goes to `/auth/spotify/callback`? Because currently, you're sending the request once you run your node app... I don't believe you meant that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Should I nest it in the `/auth/spotify/callback` route? I'll give it a go.

Comment: Oh, but you can't exactly use `code` until you get it, and currently, `request` executes once you run the program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function to `request` with `code` as the argument:

```js
function whateverName(code) {
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic Basic MmV...WU=',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/auth/spotify/callback'
    }
  };
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
  });
}

app.get("/auth/spotify/callback", (req, res) => {
  let code = req.query.code;
  whateverName(code); // Sent!
  res.send({
    "code": code
  });
})
```